# pre-commit: Differentiating between files modified and actual failure

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

It seems [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) exits with code 0 if everything is fine, and exit code 1 if any checks Fail - regardless of reason.

Is there a way (programmatically) to differentiate between failures that resulted in files  being modified (thereby fixing the problem) vs a problem that requires a user (like "E501 line too long")?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/3007

Answer (score 3):

short answer: no

slightly longer answer: no but also it also would be impossible to know if all linting would pass after formatting plus tools can both modify files and at the same time produce "errors"

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: For my purpose, I'm considering running it twice, and if it succeeds the second time, treating that as an "autorepair" event instead of a "blocker".